# NPM start script missing

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am trying to use the `npm start` command but I don't have the correct *"start"* script in my **package.json**. Can anyone please tell me the correct way to add it?

I have tried adding *"start": "node server.js"* to my scripts in **package.json** but that throws up an error:

```
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:587:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:513:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:308:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:878:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! aristophanes@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aristophanes@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-10T11_34_37_097Z-debug.log
```

So it can't find a *server.js* file. Can anyone elaborate what file exactly I'm supposed to be looking for to add to the "start" script? *Package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "aristophanes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: It can't find C:\Users\Aristophanes\server.js because there is no server.js. What are you trying to start?

Comment: Could you please share your directory structure. This should work as you describe as long as you have a server.js file next to your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `"main": "server.js"` in your package.json

Edit: You have to define the file name as `main` which contains your `server.listen` callback. Also you can start running with `node [your-server-file].js` If your file name is `index.js` node finds it automatically, no need the `main` part.

Comment: Edited. Also note that the `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\server.js'` says there is no server.js in the directory. So you are either in the wrong directory, or you named your file something else than server.js.